# Slimv backtrace doesn't show local variables

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, slimv

I've just installed Slimv to maximize lisp hacking, and I can't get anything useful out of the debugger.

If I type in the REPL

```
(+ 1 a)
```

I get the following error, which is fine

```
EVAL: variable A has no value
   [Condition of type SYSTEM::SIMPLE-UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

...and it's accompanying insane backtrace

```
Backtrace:

0: [520] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ SWANK::*SLDB-STEPPING-P* <--> NIL 
    No locals
1: [517] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ SWANK::*SLDB-LEVEL* <--> 0
2: [514] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ *PACKAGE* <--> #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP-USER>
3: <1/507> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::DEBUG-IN-EMACS>[506] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ SWANK::*SLIME-INTERRUPTS-ENABLED* <--> T
4: <1/501> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK:INVOKE-SLIME-DEBUGGER>- #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK-2-1>
5: <1/499> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK-2-1>- #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK-2-1>
6: [498] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ *DEBUGGER-HOOK* <--> NIL
7: <1/494> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION #:|877 882 (DEFINTERFACE CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK (HOOK FUN) ...)-84-3-1|>- #<COMPILED-FUNCTION #:|877 882 (DEFINTERFACE CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK (HOOK FUN) ...)-84-3-1|>
8: <1/489> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK-BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK>- #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK-2>
9: <1/486> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK-2>- #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK::SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK-2>
10: [485] handler frame for conditions SWANK::INVOKE-DEFAULT-DEBUGGER
11: [479] compiled tagbody frame for #(NIL)
12: <1/473> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK>[471] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ *DEBUGGER-HOOK* <--> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SWANK:SWANK-DEBUGGER-HOOK>
13: <1/468> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION INVOKE-DEBUGGER> 1[467] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ SYSTEM::*PRIN-STREAM* <--> #<UNBOUND>
14: [464] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ *PRINT-READABLY* <--> NIL
15: [461] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ *PRINT-ESCAPE* <--> T
16: <1/458> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION ERROR>[457] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ SYSTEM::*ACTIVE-RESTARTS* <--> (#S(RESTART :NAME SWANK::RETRY :TEST #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::DEFAULT-RESTART..
17: [454] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):  | ~ SYSTEM::*CONDITION-RESTARTS* <--> NIL
18: [450] compiled block frame for SYSTEM::CHECK-VALUE
19: <1/445> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::CHECK-VALUE>- NIL ~
```

So, what the heck is going on, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is working with the debugger then go to normal mode (press ESC)

and:

> If you place the cursor on a numbered line in the Backtrace: section
>   and press Enter (in Normal mode) then the frame locals are displayed:
>
> If you press Enter on a numbered line in the Restarts: section then
>   the corresponding restart is executed. The most frequently used
>   restarts have their own keyboard shortcuts: ,a selects the Abort, ,q
>   selects the Quit and ,n selects the contiNue restart. Let's choose
>   restart 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level by pressing ,a:

you can learn more on it with the slimv [tutorial](http://kovisoft.bitbucket.org/tutorial.html)